# How to insert value into Column Family using java/astyanax?

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

[SOLVED] -

I am not sure why, but removing the

```
m.withRow(CF_test, "acct1234")
   .incrementCounterColumn("loginCount", 1);
```

part of my code made it work. Alternatively, if someone could explain why it does so, that would be appreciated. Thank you!

---

I've been having trouble with Astyanax for Cassandra-cli. I couldn't really figure out much from the Netflix Github site, so I was looking to ask people with more firsthand experience.

How would I go about inserting rows into a Column Family that I have already created in Cassandra? Currently, my code looks like this:

```
// Inserting data
MutationBatch m = keyspace.prepareMutationBatch();


//Initialize Column family
ColumnFamily<String, String> CF_test =
new ColumnFamily<String, String>(
"users",              // Column Family Name
StringSerializer.get(),   // Key Serializer
StringSerializer.get());  // Column Serializer


m.withRow(CF_test, "default")
  .putColumn("full_name", "john", null)
  .putColumn("email", "smith", null)
  .putColumn("state", "555 Elm St", null)
  .putColumn("gender", "Male", null)
  .putColumn("birth_year", 30, null);

m.withRow(CF_test, "acct1234")
  .incrementCounterColumn("loginCount", 1);


  OperationResult<Void> result = m.execute();
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.BadRequestException: BadRequestException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=55(55), attempts=1]InvalidRequestException(why:invalid operation for non commutative columnfamily users)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:159)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:65)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:28)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$ThriftConnection.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:151)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:69)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:256)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl.executeOperation(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:485)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl.access$000(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:79)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl$1.execute(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:123)
at Test1.main(Test1.java:76)

Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:invalid operation for non commutative columnfamily users)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:20833)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:964)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:950)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl$1$1.internalExecute(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:129)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl$1$1.internalExecute(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:126)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
... 8 more
```

Creating keyspaces worked, now I'm just unable to get column families changed.

Comment: What is your column families default validator?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The validation class is UTF8Type, is that what you mean? I'm not too familiar with what a default validator is.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to add "Solved" or "Fixed". If tou found the answer yourself, *add it as an answer*. Stack Overflow allows you to accept it (although there is a short waiting period for members with a low reputation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use

```
m.withRow(CF_test, "acct1234").incrementCounterColumn("loginCount", 1);
```

(counters),

> you have to define a column family (or super column family) whose
>   columns will act as counters.

Default validation class must be set to *CounterColumnType*.

> CounterColumnType may only be set in the default_validation_class. A
>   column family either contains only counters, or no counters at all.

Take a look at [this page](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Working-with-counter-columns) that refers to [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Counters).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but removing the

```
m.withRow(CF_test, "acct1234")
   .incrementCounterColumn("loginCount", 1);
```

part of my code made it work. Alternatively, if someone could explain why it does so, that would be appreciated. Thank you!